# строка в массив и вывести количество количество символов в массиве в консоли с самими символами

Tags: map, split, length

[image: 1]

Суть задачи - строка преобразуется в массив и массив должен быть отображён в консоли вот так: метро - 5, вагон -5. Т.е. должно быть отображение количества символов в элементе массива. У меня не хватает знаний что бы это сделать, Спасибо за помощь)))

Comment: Если не хватает знаний, то решай задачу попроще, на которую хватает.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать квадратные скобки вокруг element.length внутри функции map. Функция map должна принимать функцию, определяющую, как преобразовать каждый элемент, и в данном случае, мы хотим получить длину каждого слова.

Нужно добавить стрелочную функцию (=>) для правильного определения преобразования внутри функции map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
"use strict";

const ferst = 'метро вагон';

const words = ferst.split(' ');

const newArr = words.map(element => element.length);

console.log(newArr);
</script>
```

Для вывода как самого элемента, так и количества символов в нем, можно  использовать метод forEach вместо map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
"use strict";

const ferst = 'метро вагон';

const words = ferst.split(' ');

words.forEach(element => {
  console.log(`${element} - ${element.length}`);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит, подскажите ещё момент как в консоль вывести именно сам элемент и рядом число символов в нём? Т.е. - метро - 5    Вагон-5

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Вы мне очень помогли!)